# Best strategy for "mutable" records in Erlang

Tags: data-structures, erlang

I develop the system where I assume will be many users. Each user has a profile represented inside the application as a record. To store user's profile I do the following `base64:encode_to_string(term_to_binary(Profile))`, so basically profiles stored in serialized maner.

So far everything is just fine. Now comes the question:

From time to time I do plan to extend profile functionality by adding and removing certain fields in it. My question is what is a best strategy to handle these changes in the code?

The approach I see at the moment is to do something like this:

```
Profile = get_profile(UserName),
case is_record(Profile, #profile1) of
    true ->
        % do stuff with Profile#profile1
        ok;
    _ ->
        next
end,
case is_record(Profile, #profile2) of
    true ->
        % do stuff with Profile#profile2
        ok;
    _ ->
        next
end,
```

I want to know if there are any better solutions for my task?

**Additional info:** I use is simple KV storage. It cannot store Erlang types this is why I use `State#state.player#player.chips#chips.br`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, you could use proplists.

Assume, you have stored some user profile.

```
User = [{name,"John"},{surname,"Dow"}].
store_profile(User).
```

Then, after a couple of years you decided to extend user profile with user's age.

```
User = [{name,"John"},{surname,"Dow"},{age,23}]. 
store_profile(User).
```

Now you need to get a user profile from DB

```
get_val(Key,Profile) ->
   V = lists:keyfind(Key,1,Profile),
   case V of
      {_,Val} -> Val;
      _ -> undefined
   end.

User = get_profile().
UserName = get_val(name,User).
UserAge = get_val(age,User).
```

If you get a user profile of 'version 2', you will get an actual age (23 in this particular case).

If you get a user profile of 'version 1' ('old' one), you will get 'undefined' as an age, - and then you can update the profile and store it with the new value, so it will be 'new version' entity.

So, no version conflict.

Probably, this is not the best way to do, but it might be a solution in some case.

Answer (score 1):

It strongly depend of proportion of number of records, frequency of changes and acceptable outage. I would prefer upgrade of profiles to newest version first due maintainability. You also can make system which will upgrade on-fly as mnesia does. And finally there is possibility keep code for all versions which I would definitely not prefer. It is maintenance nightmare.

Anyway when `is_record/2` is allowed in guards I would prefer

```
case Profile of
    X when is_record(X, profile1) ->
        % do stuff with Profile#profile1
        ok;
    X when is_record(X, profile2) -> 
        % do stuff with Profile#profile2
        ok
end
```

Notice there is not catch all clause because what you would do with unknown record type? It is error so fail fast!

You have many other options e.g. hack like:

```
case element(1,Profile) of
    profile1 ->
        % do stuff with Profile#profile1
        ok;
    profile2 -> 
        % do stuff with Profile#profile2
        ok
end
```

or something like

```
{_, F} = lists:keyfind({element(1,Profile), size(Profile)},
    [{{profile1, record_info(size, profile1)}, fun foo:bar/1},
     {{profile2, record_info(size, profile2)}, fun foo:baz/1}]),
F(Profile).
```

and many other possibilities.

Comment: Yeah, more or less what I do now... I think I will have to keep all versions + implement migration algorithm between versions... So, when old profile is loaded, it will determine it's version to know from whee to where it should migrate... Sound like self foot-shoot.(((

Answer (score 1):

**The best approach is to have the copy of the serialized (profile) and also a copy of the same but in record form. Then , each time changes are made to the record-form profile, changes are also made to the serialized profile of the same user ATOMICALLY (within the same transaction!).**  The code that modifies the users record profile, should always recompute the new serialized form which, to you, is the external representation of the users record

```
-record(record_prof,{name,age,sex}).
-record(myuser,{
            username,
            record_profile = #record_prof{},
            serialized_profile
        }).

change_profile(Username,age,NewValue)->
    %% transaction starts here....
    [MyUser] = mnesia:read({myuser,Username}),
    Rec = MyUser#myuser.record_profile,
    NewRec = Rec#record_prof{age = NewValue},
    NewSerialised = serialise_profile(NewRec),
    NewUser = MyUser#myuser{
                    record_profile = NewRec,
                    serialized_profile = NewSerialised
                },
    write_back(NewUser),
    %% transaction ends here.....
    ok.
```

So whatever the serialize function is doing, that's that. But this always leaves an overhead free profile change. We thereby keep the serialized profile as always the correct representation of the record profile at all times. When changes occur to the record profile, the serialized form must also be recomputed (transactional) so as to have integrity.

Comment: Hi Joshua, thank you very much for your suggestion! My problem is a little bit different. I store profiles in persistent storage and they could be there for ages. See, for example in 2011 we have profile version 1.0, after few years say in 2015 I have profile version 73.6. SO it is big difference between stored profile (which was never called to load) and the current one. My problem is how to maintain this stuff properly...

Comment: The storage having nothing to do with Erlang storage mechanisms, is it so ? lets say is it `Mnesia` ? If not, am i correct to think that your application is in erlang but your storage cannot take erlang types directly and hence the need to serialize ? So if the storage is not in erlang terms, you needed a way of serializing the record profiles. So your question is on how to handle the whole scenario ? expand your question a bit (please) so it includes storage information, and what application and how it will be getting the profiles ? we need to get you very well. Thanks :)

Comment: Just added some info in the topic. So, I use simple KV database. It doesn't know anything about Erlang types. I would love to use Mnesia, but I need hard copy of my data - my KV storage is kind of persistent storage :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use some *extensible* data serialization format such as JSON or Google Protocol Buffers.

Both of these formats support adding new fields without breaking backwards compatibility. By using them you won't need to introduce explicit versioning to your serialized data structures.

Choosing between the two formats depends on your use case. For instance, using Protocol Buffers is more reliable, whereas JSON is easier to get started with.

Comment: I also was thinking about protobuf or JSON. I prefer JSON, because my xp shows that with protobuf more troubles than actual benefits.

Comment: Even extensible data serialization doesn't prevent you from necessity to break backward compatibility. It would force you to do only backward compatible changes which will end up as pile of mess in few months in rapidly evolving project. Adding keys is not only option, you sometimes have to change cardinality of data, merging keys, removing keys and so on.

Comment: Hynek, this is not a silver bullet of course. But you kind of missed the point. Which is more extensible - JSON or serialized erlang records? My suggestion certanly solves the described problem. Also, if one is not mindful about what she is doing and manages to create a complete mess in a few months, I'd argue no tool would be of much help.

Comment: I would say that there is no silver bullet solution at the moment for my question. You guys both suggested solutions where I have to keep code for each version of my profile records. Actually I don't see possibility to avoid it at the moment. Of course I have some technics to minimize code-mess and impact of code duplication... Anyways waiting for other suggestions... Maybe somebody already faced and nicely solved it?

Comment: I'm confused. The only change between versions that you mentioned is adding/removing fields. JSON can perfectly cover this use case without introducing explicit versions. All you need to do is check if a field is present before accessing it.

Comment: Anton, you re right. If I introduce code that transforms JSON->Record that everything is fine. And actually I am thinking about it. But at the moment I do `base64:encode_to_string(term_to_binary(Profile))` for serialization, this is why it won't work for me. So I think JSON->Recors is the only option...

Comment: There are a couple of other options: 1) you could drop records and use something like [Erlson](https://github.com/alavrik/erlson) or [kvc](https://github.com/etrepum/kvc) for manipulating JSON; 2) Or you could use [Piqi](https://github.com/alavrik/piqi-erlang) to automate JSON<->record conversion (this would be not much different from using Protobuf, though).